# INotifyPropertyChanged UI Hang

Tags: wpf, deadlock, inotifypropertychanged

I have an WPF application which contains many classes that support INotifyProprtyChange interface. The property on this classes are changed at high rate from different threads and the problem is that in some cases application UI thread hangs , along with the UI thread other threads that have code calling PropertyChange also hangs while trying update properties.

I did a deadlock check with Windbg but it could detect none.
Now i looked at the stack trace of the threads holding locks and what i always see is that at least one same or different thread has

```
00000000002d0ab8 000000007712908a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 00000000002d0ab8] System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.WaitHelper(IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)
00000000002d13b0 000000007712908a [GCFrame: 00000000002d13b0] 
00000000002d16c8 000000007712908a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 00000000002d16c8] System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock.AcquireReaderLockInternal(Int32)
00000000002d17f0 000007fef1bcf1a0 MS.Internal.ReaderWriterLockWrapper.get_ReadLock()
00000000002d1830 000007fef1ba8d44 System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
```

and another

```
000000001f64d138 000000007738186a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000001f64d138] System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock.AcquireReaderLockInternal(Int32)
000000001f64d260 000007fef1bcf1a0 MS.Internal.ReaderWriterLockWrapper.get_ReadLock()
000000001f64d2a0 000007fef1ba8d44 System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
```

So its looks like PropertyChangedEventManager wait for some thread to complete while other threads wait to acquire lock?

Now i am having troubles figuring out why this occurs as its sporadic and usually happens when there is many property change events. From what i see other threads in application that not calling property change continue to run normally.

Comment: you could write a Logfile to finde the Property which produces your error. every time PropertyChanged the first thing should be saving the property name in a file if your problem now occurs the last property in the List should be the one which created the problem

Comment: Those calls to NotifyProprtyChanged get stacked.  Try changing the backing variable then just call NotifyProprtyChanged once.

Comment: @Blam Well i did some changes and still problem occurs but with a different type of code blocking. BTW the problem usually occurs on resolution change.   

[code]
[Managed to Native Transition] 
  WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) Unknown
  [Native to Managed Transition] 
  WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(object sender = {System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction}, System.EventArgs args = {System.EventArgs}) Unknown

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know PropertyNotifyChanged is only supported in the UI thread.

Just guessing. In bigger environments one problem happends quiet easy: 2 properties update each other endlessly. The setter of prop A calls the setter of prop B which in turn calls the setter of A again. Usually of course not that obvious as described but could be worth to look at.

Comment: As far as i can see there is no circular updates for the properties. What happens is that same or different properties on the same class is updated from different threads and this might happen quite often. The hang is always occur when ProperychangeManager on the main thread holds update lock and waits for event delivery completion.